# Assign each value to a range on dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an array `states` like this

```
[(1,3), (3,5), (5,7), (7,9)]
```

and a dataframe `df` like this

```
   l  y
0  a  8
1  b  3
2  c  7
3  d  4
4  e  1
```

I need to assign the index of the belonging range on `states` to get something like this

```
   l  y state
0  a  8   3
1  b  3   0
2  c  7   2
3  d  4   1
4  e  1   0
```

for each range in `states`, the `y` values have to belong to the range `(start, end]` except in the first range where `1` does belongs to `(1,3)`

so far I have this

```
def asign(x):
    for a,b in states:
        if x>=a and x<=b:
            return states.index((a,b))
df['state'] = df.y.apply(asign)
```

but I need a faster and more efficient way for larger data frames, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pandas.cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins=pd.Series([1,3,5,7,9, np.inf])   
df['state'] = pd.cut(df.y, bins=bins, labels=bins.index[:-1], include_lowest=True)
```

Output:

```
In [113]: df
Out[113]:
   l  y state
0  a  8     3
1  b  3     0
2  c  7     2
3  d  4     1
4  e  1     0
```

How to convert your `states` list of tuples to flat `pd.Series`:

```
In [125]: states
Out[125]: [(1, 3), (3, 5), (5, 7), (7, 9)]

In [126]: bins = pd.Series(np.unique(list(sum(states, ()))))

In [127]: bins
Out[127]:
0    1
1    3
2    5
3    7
4    9
dtype: int32

In [128]: bins.tolist()
Out[128]: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid looping over all rows using `.apply()` and instead assign `states` in a vectorized way:

```
df['states'] = 0
for i, state in enumerate(states):
    df.loc[(df.y > state[0]) & (df.y <= state[1]), 'states'] = i
```

to get:

```
   l  y  states
0  a  8       3
1  b  3       0
2  c  7       2
3  d  4       1
4  e  1       0
```